# System of Equations- CEMC

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the System of Equations
$$x^2+x^2y^2+x^2y^4=525  $$
$$x+xy+xy^2= 35  $$
find the sum of the real $y$ values that satisfy the system.

Comment: Hi what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like a homework problem !!
This is an algebra problem. Solve both equations for x in terms of y.  Equate them to get a single equation in y. Once you have equated them, put the y terms onto one side of the equation, maybe by cross multiplying.  Square both sides. Hint: $y^4 +y^2+1=(y^2-y+1)(y^2+y+1)$  You will use that factored form to remove a $(y^2+y+1)$ term.  After that, it is just finish the grind.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. $1+k^2+k^4=(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f)$
2. $\frac{525}{35}=15$
3. $\frac{35}{15}=\frac{7}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Factoring the left hand sides of the two equations gives:

$$x^2=\frac{525}{(y^2+y+1)(y^2-y+1)}$$
$$x=\frac{35}{y^2+y+1}$$

Therefore we eliminate $x$ and solve for $y$.

$$\frac{525}{(y^2+y+1)(y^2-y+1)}=\frac{1225}{(y^2+y+1)^2}\implies 3(y^2+y+1)=7(y^2-y+1)$$
$$\implies 2y^2-5y+2=0\implies(2y-1)(y-2)=0\implies y\in\left\{\frac{1}{2},2\right\}$$

The sum of these is $\displaystyle\frac{5}{2}$.